# Using UNION with Sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, union, sequel

I want to define a SQL-command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM WOMAN
UNION
SELECT * FROM MEN
```

I tried to define this with the following code sequence in Ruby + Sequel:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel::Database.new()
sel = DB[:women].union(DB[:men])
puts sel.sql
```

The result is (I made some pretty print on the result):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `women` 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM `men`
) AS 't1'
```

There is an additional (superfluous?) `SELECT`.

If I define multiple `UNION` like in this code sample

```
sel = DB[:women].union(DB[:men]).union(DB[:girls]).union(DB[:boys])
puts sel.sql
```

I get more superfluous SELECTs.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `women` 
      UNION 
      SELECT * FROM `men`
    ) AS 't1' 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM `girls`
  ) AS 't1' 
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM `boys`
) AS 't1'
```

I detected no problem with it up to now, the results seem to be the same.

My questions:

- Is there a reason for the additional `select`s (beside sequel internal procedures)
- Can I avoid the selects?
- Can I get problems with this additional selects? (Any Performance issue?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the extra SELECTs is so code like `DB[:girls].union(DB[:boys]).where(:some_column=>1)` operates properly.  You can use `DB[:girls].union(DB[:boys], :from_self=>false)` to not wrap it in the extra SELECTs, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-union).

Comment: Thanks. I'm always astonished, how good sequel works - and that I always miss it from the documentation (I'm sure I looked at the union documentation).